# JavaScript to convert JSON to CSV without values in " "

Tags: javascript

I am using below JS code to convert JSON data to CSV data,

```
function executeScript(event) {
    var json = event.getParameter("jsondata");
    var fields = Object.keys(json[0]);
    var replacer = function(key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value };
    var csv = json.map(function(row){
     return fields.map(function(fieldName){
     return JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)
  }).join('|');
})
csv.unshift(fields.join('|')); // add header column
 csv = csv.join('\r\n');
  event.log(csv);
}
```

But using this code i am getting below response :

```
Username|Identifier|First name|Last name
"booker12"|"9012"|"Rachel"|"Booker"
"grey07"|"2070"|"Laura"|"Grey"
"johnson81"|"4848"|"Craig"|"Johnson"
"jenkins46"|"9346"|"Mary"|"Jenkins"
"smith79"|"5079"|"Jamie"|"Smith"
```

But as an output i need,

```
Username|Identifier|First name|Last name
booker12|9012|Rachel|Booker
grey07|2070|Laura|Grey
johnson81|4848|Craig|Johnson
jenkins46|9346|Mary|Jenkins
smith79|5079|Jamie|Smith
```

Can anyone suggest how to get values in CSV without ""?

input data:

```
[{
  "Username": "booker12",
  "Identifier": "9012",
  "First name": "Rachel",
  "Last name": "Booker"
}, {
  "Username": "grey07",
  "Identifier": "2070",
  "First name": "Laura",
  "Last name": "Grey"
}, {
  "Username": "johnson81",
  "Identifier": "4848",
  "First name": "Craig",
  "Last name": "Johnson"
}, {
  "Username": "jenkins46",
  "Identifier": "9346",
  "First name": "Mary",
  "Last name": "Jenkins"
}, {
  "Username": "smith79",
  "Identifier": "5079",
  "First name": "Jamie",
  "Last name": "Smith"
}]
```

Comment: Remove the `JSON.stringify()` call as, assuming from the output, `row[fieldname]` returns a single string value. If that doesn't work for you, could you please edit the question to provide an example of the input data from `event.getParameter('jsondata')` so that we can create a working example of the problem.

Comment: Using the method mentioned above, you could also use the `??` operator ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)) to fall back to an empty string for `null` values: `row[fieldname] ?? ''`

Comment: You will still need to quote values that contain `|` or new lines and you also need to double the `"`.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question - I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you call `JSON.stringify()` on a single string value. This is the cause of the double-quoted strings. It's also redundant and can be removed.

In addition, it's worth noting that the code can be simplified. You can use the OR operator to coalesce null values to empty strings due to the falsy nature of `null`. You can also use `Object.values()` o build the data body in the same manner you use `Object.keys()` to build the header row.

Here's a working example:

```js
const buildRow = arr => arr.join('|') + '\r\n';

function executeScript(event) {
  var json = accountData; // event.getParameter("jsondata");
  
  var csv = buildRow(Object.keys(json[0])); // header row
  csv += json.map(r => buildRow(Object.values(r).filter(v => v || ''))).join(''); // body
  return csv;
}

const accountData = [{Username:"booker12",Identifier:"9012","First name":"Rachel","Last name":"Booker"},{Username:"grey07",Identifier:"2070","First name":"Laura","Last name":"Grey"},{Username:"johnson81",Identifier:"4848","First name":"Craig","Last name":"Johnson"},{Username:"jenkins46",Identifier:"9346","First name":"Mary","Last name":"Jenkins"},{Username:"smith79",Identifier:"5079","First name":"Jamie","Last name":"Smith"}];
console.log(executeScript());
```

As a side note, I'd suggest you rename the `json` variable, as it holds an array, not JSON, and your logic would be better structured if you passed the array in to the function as an argument instead of relying on a higher-scoped variable.

Comment: I am using this javascript in GCP tool where i can not take Object.values() function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what *is* and what *is not* available in GCP tools. I am surprised to hear that the `Object` methods `.keys()` and `.values()` should not be available there. The following is an example of an event triggered function that can also receive a data array through a parameter

```js
const accountData = [{Username:"booker12",Identifier:"9012","First name":"Rachel","Last name":"Booker"},{Username:"grey07",Identifier:"2070","First name":"Laura","Last name":"Grey"},{Username:"johnson81",Identifier:"4848","First name":"Craig","Last name":"Johnson"},{Username:"jenkins46",Identifier:"9346","First name":"Mary","Last name":"Jenkins"},{Username:"smith79",Identifier:"5079","First name":"Jamie","Last name":"Smith"}];

function executeScript(dat) { return function(ev){
  console.log( 
    [Object.keys(dat[0])]
    .concat(dat.map(r=>Object.values(r)))
    .map(r=>r.join("|"))
    .join("\n") );
}}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",executeScript(accountData));
```

```html
<button>make CSV</button>
```